# How to pass parameters to routes using a Tab Navigator NOT stack navigator

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-navigation, expo

Im using the react navigation library, specifically `createBottomTabNavigator`

The docs at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html explain how to pass parameters between routes using a stack navigator but Im using a tab navigator and I cant find anything that jumps out to me explaining how to do it in a tab navigation setup

My tab navigator in App.js is

```
const BottomTabMenu = createBottomTabNavigator (
  {
    WatchList: { screen: WatchListScreen },
    Alerts: { screen: AlertsScreen },
    Analytics: { screen: AnalyticsScreen },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'WatchList',
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'WatchList') { iconName = 'md-list'; }  
        if (routeName === 'Alerts') { iconName = 'md-alert'; }  
        if (routeName === 'Analytics') { iconName = 'md-analytics'; }  
        if (routeName === 'Settings') { iconName = 'md-settings'; }

        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(BottomTabMenu);
```

The watchList route holds a jsonfile called symbols that I want to pass to the alerts route which is in alertsScreen.js

```
export default class WatchListScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            symbols: [],
        }
    }  
LOTS OF OTHER STUFF
```

ALERTSSCREEN.JS

```
export default class AlertsScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        //according to the docs, this is how to receive in the props
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const jsonWatchList = navigation.getParam('jsonWatchList', '[]');

        return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>blah blah blah</Text>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

According to the docs the line I need to pass the data would be something like this

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Alerts', {
              jsonWatchList: [lots of data here],
            });
```

Only problem is I dont know where it should go.

Answer (score -3):

It is well documented in your link (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html).
It explains how pass params between route. It doesn't matter if you are using a `stackNavigator` or a `createBottomTabNavigator`

Pass your parameters like you wanted to do :

`this.props.navigation.navigate('jsonWatchList', {
   jsonWatchList: [lots of data here],
});`

And in your other screen, get them like :

`const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('jsonWatchList');`

Comment: Where does it go? In the stack navigator example it's within a button that changes route. Tab navigation doesn't use buttons

Comment: You can do it from anywhere you want. Let's say you are on screen A, and you want go to screen B with some params, it will be like `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB', { data: YourData });`

Comment: I want to do it when I press the tab navigator but the code for that exists in app.js not watchlist.js

Comment: It's weird that you want to pass the same parameter in any case. Can't you fetch the data you need in the appropriate screen ?
If you want really do that, you might consider create your tabBar component and pass it to the `createBottomTabNavigator` with the prop `tabBarComponent`

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean "pass the same parameter"? I want to pass a json to another route when I press its tab navigator. I'm not using buttons and every example on the net I can find uses an onpress. Tabnavigators don't have an onpress

Comment: Ok I understand
The only way i see to do it is, you have to set the params when you have them in the `WatchListScreen` like `navigation.setParams({ jsonWatchList: [lots of data here] });`
You don't have to try to catch a `onPress` somewhere to set the param. You can set it immediately after you got the data you need.

Then, when you navigate, you can get them.